Taking K elements from an infinite set sum, the expectation of getting a duplicate element exactly the Kth time
First, the probability of selecting $ k $ elements from an $ n $-element set, where the $ k $th selection is the first time a duplicate occurs, is given by:
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k-1} (k-1)!(k-1)}{n^k}
$$
This equation represents the selection of $ k-1 $ elements, multiplied by all permutations of these $k-1$ elements, and then the $k$th selection which must be one of the previously selected $k-1$ elements.
The expectation of $k$ is given by:
$$
E(k)=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n\\
 k-1\\
\end{array} \right) (k-1)!(k-1)k}{n^k}=}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{n!(k-1)!(k-1)k}{\left( n-k+1 \right) !\left( k-1 \right) !n^k}=}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{k\left( k-1 \right) n!}{\left( n-k+1 \right) !n^k}}
$$

Then I got stuck. I need to use the Stirling formula to find the answer for this:
$
n! = \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{12n} + \theta \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right) \right)
$
How do I derive to this? $$ E(k) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \theta \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)} $$

Let $X$ be the number of items chosen, including the first duplicate. I can only prove that $EX\sim \sqrt{n\pi/2}$, which is slightly less precise than $\sqrt{n\pi/2-1/3+\Theta(n^{-1/2})}$. Perhaps you will find this partial answer to be helpful.
Below, I will apply Stirling's approximation to the factorials $n!$ and $(n-k)!$. For this to work, we need $n$ and $n-k$ to be large, so this only applies when $k\ll n$.
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=k+1)
= \frac{k\binom nkk!}{n^{k+1}}
&= \frac{kn!}{(n-k)!n^{k+1}}
\\&\sim \frac{k\cdot n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n^{k+1}(n-k)^{n-k}e^{-(n-k)}\sqrt{2\pi(n-k)}}\tag{$k\ll n$}
\\&=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}\cdot \frac{k}n\cdot e^{-k}\frac{n^{n-k}}{(n-k)^{n-k}} 
%\\&=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}\cdot \frac{k}n\cdot e^{-k}\cdot \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-n}\cdot \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^k 
\end{align}
$$
If we are going to find an approximate equivalent for the sum of $kP(X=k)$, we need to find an approximate equivalent for each summand, $P(X=k+1)$. For this purposes, it is helpful to work with $\log P(X=k+1)$ first. I will just focus on the $e^{-k}\frac{n^{n-k}}{(n-k)^{n-k}} $ portion, because the log of $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}\cdot \frac{k}n$ is negligible in comparison.
$$
\begin{align}
\log \left(e^{-k}\frac{n^{n-k}}{(n-k)^{n-k}}  \right)
&= -k+(n-k)\log\left(\frac{n}{n-k}\right)\\
&= -k-(n-k)\log\left(1-\frac kn\right)\\
&= -k-(n-k)\left(-\frac kn-\frac12\left(\frac kn\right)^2+O\left(\frac{k^3}{n^3}\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{-k^2}{2n}+O\left(\frac{k^3}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
This shows, noting $\sqrt{n/(n-k)}=\exp(-\frac12\log(1-k/n))=\exp(O(k/n))$,  that
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=k+1)&=\sqrt{\frac n{n-k}}\cdot  \frac kn \cdot \exp\left(-k^2/2n\right)\cdot \exp\left(O(k^3/n^{2})\right)
\\&= \frac kn \cdot \exp\left(-k^2/2n\right)\cdot \exp\left(O(k^3/n^{2}+k/n)\right)
\\&= \frac kn \cdot \exp\left(-k^2/2n\right)\cdot \exp\left(O(k^3/n^{2})\right)
\end{align}
$$
This means we have a good approximation of $P(X=k+1)\sim \frac kn\exp(-k^2/2n)$ whenever $k=o(n^{2/3})$, because then $\exp(O(k^3/n^2))\sim 1$.
We are finally ready to evaluate the expected value. I will split this calculation into two sums, one where $k<n^{3/5}$, and one where $k>n^{3/5}$.
$$
\begin{align}
EX= \sum_{k=0}^{n^{3/5}} kP(X=k)
 &\sim \sum_{k=0}^{n^{3/5}}\frac{k^2}n e^{-k^2/2n}
\\&=\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n^{3/5}} (k/\sqrt{n})^2\cdot e^{-(k/\sqrt{n})^2/2}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{n}}
\\&\sim \sqrt{n}\int_0^{\infty} x^2e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi n/2}
\end{align}
$$
In the regime where $k>n^{3/5}$, we use  $\log(1-x)\le -x$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
P(X=k+1)
&=\frac kn \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)
\\&\le 1\cdot \exp\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}-\frac in\right)
\\&=\exp(-k(k-1)/2n)
\\&\le \exp(-n^{3/5}(n^{3/5}-1)/2n)\tag{$k>n^{3/5}$}
\\&\sim \exp(-n^{1/5}/2)
\end{align}
$$
This proves that $\sum_{k=n^{3/5}}^nkP(X=k)\le n^2\exp(-n^{1/5}/2)$ is negligible compared to the first sum.

Very good answers. There were some fancy tricks that I hadn't seen before, and at the same time you wrote it in a way that I could basically read it;:), thanks!
There are three small problems though:
1.

noting $\sqrt{n/(n-k)}=\exp(-\frac12\log(1-k/n))=\exp(O(k/n))$.

Why does $\exp(O(k/n))$ here not seem to carry over into the following equation, which might have a term $\exp(O(k^4/n^3))$ if it did?
2.$$=\exp(-k(k-1)/2n)
\le \exp(-n^{1/5})$$
The less-than-equal here doesn't make sense to me.
3.$n^2\exp (-n^{1/5})$ Why is it trivial compared to $\sqrt{(\pi n/2)}$?

Thanks for the feedback. For (1),  note that $k\le n$, so $$O(k/n)\le O(k/n· 1· k)=O(k/n\cdot k/n \cdot k).$$ Therefore, when you multiply $\exp(O(k/n))$ with $\exp(O(k^2/n^3)$, you get $\exp(O(k/n+ k^2/n^3)$, and the $k^2/n^3$ term is dominant. For (3), let $f(n)=\sqrt{\pi n/2}$, let $g(n)=n^2\exp(-n^{1/5})$, and compare $\log f$ to $\log g$. For (2), I will edit my answer to explain.
